# Add values to a sum in each multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So the formula bellow is working fine and it's searching in a named range for multiple keys and counting how many exist of each one in that named range and then multiplying it for a specific value, for example:

- Named range from B2 to E2

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | - | Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3 | Day 4 | Total |
| 2 | Jan | F | B | F | F | 11 |
| 3 | Feb | B | B |  |  | 4 |

I'm just going to show code in F2 because F3 is the same just with a different named range

```
INDIRECT($A2) -> This is a named range there's multiple of them
'Info'!$B$9 -> F
'Info'!$B$10 -> B
'Info'!$C$9 -> 3
'Info'!$C$10 -> 2

=SUM(
        COUNTIFS(INDIRECT($A2);'Info'!$B$9)*'Info'!$C$9;
        COUNTIFS(INDIRECT($A2);'Info'!$B$10)*'Info'!$C$10;
)
```

What I would like to do now is having a second row (**3**) bellow where I can add extra values to the count and make it add that values on that specific key above so the multiplication is done correctly for example:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | - | Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3 | Day 4 | Total |
| 2 | Jan | F | B | F | F | 26 |
| 3 | JanExtra | 1 | 6 |  |  | 15 |
| 4 | Feb | B | B |  |  | 4 |
| 5 | FebExtra |  |  |  |  | 0 |

Any idea of how can I accomplish that with the code above? I'm actually stuck here and not having any ideas, thanks in advance.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Here it is: [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mtrkEw2YtLUH8Xb_LltKBulvsplfFGF1ojsdC1VdWUA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: how did you calculate 15 in F3 in your question example?

Comment: Let's think in terms of Hours, so F should always be 3h so sum all F and do x*3, Same for B but B is only 2h, the number 1 and 6 means that I want to add 1 more hour to that day shift and 6 is the same but for another day 


In Jan I did 11h if I sum all standard shifts, but I did extra hours in 2 different days lets say day2 I did 6 hours more, so on row 2 it's just doing 1*2, but now since I add that row 3 and the 6 bellows it then I want to add that 6 to the B calculation and the same for F with the respective value

Comment: I see. so there is multiplication between row 2 and row 3. shouldnt there be addition instead of multiplication?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A; ".*Extra"); 
 IFERROR(1*FLATTEN(SPLIT("♀♂"&MMULT(FILTER(B2:AF; REGEXMATCH(A2:A; ".*Extra"))*
 FILTER(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:AF; Info!A2:B; 2; 0)); NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2:A; ".*Extra"))); 
 TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B:AF))^0); "♂")); 0); 
 MMULT(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:AF; Info!A2:B; 2; 0); B2:AF)*1; TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B:AF))^0)+
 IFERROR(1*FLATTEN(SPLIT(MMULT(FILTER(B2:AF; REGEXMATCH(A2:A; ".*Extra"))*
 FILTER(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:AF; Info!A2:B; 2; 0)); NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2:A; ".*Extra"))); 
 TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B:AF))^0)&"♂♀"; "♂")); 0)))
```

[image]